# SQL Server Management Studio can't recognize .bak file

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to restore a db from Microsoft (AdventureWorks2012). However, when I try to restore the `.bak` file, it seems like SSMS doesn't recognize it and I get an error:

> No backup set selected to be restored

I gave full permissions to the folder which contains the `.bak` file.

Steps I've taken to restore the `.bak` file:

- Right click on DB -> Restore DB -> From device (selected the `.bak` file location) -> To Database (selected the DB destination)

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: there is a space after "backup"

Comment: The problem is where i select the .bak file in the 'From Device' option. I don't know why, but it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Are you sure this file is valid and not corrupt? Try right clicking on your bak file, go to properties, uncheck "Read Only" and the other option something like "Allow untrusted file" from web (I can't remember the option specifically at the moment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the error message that typically coincides with trying to restore a backup from a newer version on an older version. And it looks like you have sql server 10.5 in your screen which is 2008r2. And you are trying to restore AW2012. That will never work. You can't restore a newer version to an older version.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the help provided!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below VERIFYONLY option to understand more about the issue:

USE master
RESTORE  VERIFYONLY FROM DISK='C:\Share\DBName.bak'

In my case, I got the below error when VERIFYONLY option was used:

The path specified by "E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DBName.mdf" is not in a valid directory.
Directory lookup for the file "F:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\DBName_log.ldf" failed with the operating system error 3

It was expecting the folder 'E:\Program Files'. As it was not there in my PC, I fixed it by following RESTORE WITH MOVE option:

RESTORE DATABASE DBName FROM DISK = 'C:\Share\DBName.bak'
WITH
MOVE 'DBName' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DBName.mdf',
MOVE 'DBName_Log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DBName_Log.ldf',
RECOVERY, REPLACE, STATS = 10;