# I can not restore my database SQL Server Management Studio can't recognize my .bak files

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to restore a DB from the class. However, when I try to restore the .bak file, it seems like SSMS doesn't recognize it.

I gave full permissions to the folder which contains the .bak file (it is the default backup folder of ms SQL studio).

Steps I've taken to restore the .bak file:

Right click on DB -> Restore DB -> From device (selected the .bak file location) -> To Database (selected the DB destination)

Like here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup

The DB is not corrupt I checked 2 other DB same result so I have no idea what is the problem

Here images:

[image]

I can not see the DB and I have almost the latest version of MS SQL studio so I can not understand what is going on here and why I can not restore DBs

I checked here:
[restore database in ssms 2017 selected bak file in device option and showing nothing in Backup sets to restore option and disable Ok button too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51908865/restore-database-in-ssms-2017-selected-bak-file-in-device-option-and-showing-not)

and here:
[SQL Server Management Studio can't recognize .bak file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50241312/sql-server-management-studio-cant-recognize-bak-file)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0FpXwQfBaU

It should be easy and simple like the video above but like I said above something is wrong here and I do not know what is it.
Image of my SQL version

[image]

Comment: You haven't selected a database to restore to in that image.

Comment: Do you have full permissions to read from that folder?

Comment: Please post the version of SSMS and the version of SQL Server you are using

Comment: @Larnu I did look at the youtube video I did the same thing it should automatically fill the other fields

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT I did the link in the bottom of the my post

Comment: It's not the OP that needs permission, it's the service account that needs it. @LittleBobbyTables . (Though considering the path, I would expect it to).

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Yes like I said and It is the default folder  the backup folder of MS SQL Studio

Comment: @Larnu -- you're correct, I should have been more clear on "you"

Comment: @Larnu what do you say? I did exactly like in the youtube video as I said and I edit my post with the SQL version

Comment: I haven't watched the Youtube Video; with respect the users here shouldn't need to watch a video to try and understand what it is you've done (especially when I've heard people say "I followed the instructions step my step", and that actually hadn't).

Comment: @Larnu The video is 1minute but anyway what is the problem then? you first said I did not select the database which is not true so what is the problem?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? I can't speak for everybody but I have no interest in watching a video of your issue when you could just tell us the problem. And of course, youtube is blocked for many people which makes it not a great way to share information.

Comment: Do you see that box under Destination that says "Database:"? You need to type in the name for your new database there.

Comment: There is no Error message except no backset selected to restore like in the picture I posted,  to sum up, I press Ok after selecting my bak file from the backup folder of ms SQL default folder and nothing showing in Destination and Backup sets to retore

Comment: @SeanLange yes I saw it but it does not change anything the name should be full fill automatically like in the youtube video I posted

Comment: Again....I am not going to watch a video about how to restore a database. And yes you DO need to specify a name. Have you tried that?

Comment: @SeanLange I said I did but nothing happens

Comment: Maybe the backup is corrupt? Maybe your service account doesn't have permission? Did you try clicking the Verify button? This is really hard to debug with nothing to go on.

Comment: @SeanLange No the backup is not corrupt because my friend was able to restore it with his 2014 SQL I have 2018 version.
Moreover yes I do have permission on the user and on the folder because it is the default user/folder, you did not read my post

Comment: Yeah I was speculating based on experience and guess work. We don't have your backup file and can't see your screen while you go through this process. Hope you get it figured out.

Comment: Only thing I can guess is that you are trying to restore a backup from a newer version of sql server to an older one. Please note that the version of SSMS is not relevant here. It is the version of the sql server. Have you tried doing a restore header only? You also said something about permissions, are you 100% certain those permissions were given to the service account?

Comment: @SeanLange How can I check my sql server version? and what do you mean by "Have you tried doing a restore header only"?
And yes I am 100% certain I have all those permissions on the service account

Comment: RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK='full path to backup file' If you don't see details in the output that is an indication something is wrong with the backup. To check the version you execute this query. select @@version

Comment: Seems there is lots of people encountering this. Have you looked at any of these pages? https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+no+backupset+selected+to+be+restored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you (i mean the **service account**) got full permissions on the folder where the `.bak` file sitting and file not corrupted you should be able to restore without any issue, but there are times things fail in GUI and work perfectly with command line. not sure the issue might be exists one of the [fix of SSMS release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

However, you probably want to try following:

1. Verify the backup file - it does the verification of backup file and detects any error/corruption within backup file

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\YourbackupLocation\DbName.bak';
```

2. Read the header - it returns information of backup file i.e. DB Version, appended backup files, LSN info and database recovery model etc..

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\YourbackupLocation\DbName.bak';
```

3. Get list of file names from backup - This will be helpful if the file location is different from the source server from where the backup was created

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\YourbackupLocation\DbName.bak' ;
```

4. Restore backup - actual restore via T-SQL

```
RESTORE Backup DBName FROM DISK = 'C:\YourbackupLocation\DbName.bak' with replace, recovery, stats;
```

To relocate files

```
RESTORE Backup DBName FROM DISK = 'C:\YourbackupLocation\DbName.bak' 
with replace, recovery, stats
--- Get the logical name from the result of "RESTORE FILELISTONLY" command
move 'DBName' to 'C:\NewLocation\DBName.mdf',
move 'DBName_Log' to 'C:\NewLocation\DBName_log.ldf' ;
```